# Error "Element.get: Parameter 'object' is required" mapping to a list in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, function

I'm running my code where I create weekly averages of a variables which are mapped to a list of days of year (DOY).

```
var SSTA_7d =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
      return DOY.map(function(d) {
      d = ee.Number(d);
      var SSTA_date = series_daily.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(d, d.add(7), 'day_of_year'));
                      
      var img_last = ee.Image(SSTA_date.sort('system:time_start',true).first());
      var size = SSTA_date.size();

      var SSTA_filtered_7d = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(size.eq(0),
                                            ee.Image.constant(0).toFloat(),
                                            ee.Image(series_daily.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                                            .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(d, d.add(7), 'day_of_year'))
                                            .mean()
                                            )));
      
      return SSTA_filtered_7d.set('year', y)
              .set('DOY', d)
              .set('system:time_start', img_last.get('system:time_start'));

  });
  }).flatten()
);
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
ImageCollection (Error)
Element.get: Parameter 'object' is required.
```

From reading it might be because the image collection I'm using is empty or a server side issue. But I can't quite figure out where the issue lies. or why the image collection is empty if that's the case. My full code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmjw1280%2FSTRESS_SCORE%3AReef%20health%20variables%2FDHW_NEW%20(copy)). Lines 118-141.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error pops up because **img_last** images doesn't have a 'system:time_start'. You can corroborate that commenting set method as in following snippet code. However, another issue appears because you are trying to map an empty **HS_SSTA_7d** **ImageCollection**. So, I also commented printing **DHW_HS**.

```
.
.
.

var SSTA_7d =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
      return DOY.map(function(d) {
      d = ee.Number(d);
      var SSTA_date = series_daily.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(d, d.add(7), 'day_of_year'));
                      
      var img_last = ee.Image(SSTA_date.sort('system:time_start',true).first());
      var size = SSTA_date.size();

      var SSTA_filtered_7d = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(size.eq(0),
                                            ee.Image.constant(0).toFloat(),
                                            ee.Image(series_daily.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                                            .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(d, d.add(7), 'day_of_year'))
                                            .mean()
                                            )));
      
      return SSTA_filtered_7d.set('year', y)
              .set('DOY', d);
              //.set('system:time_start', img_last.get('system:time_start'));

  });
  }).flatten()
);
.
.
.
//print(DHW_HS);
```

For additional corroboration of that you can delete **.first** method in **img_last** variable preserving its set 'system:time_start' method; as in following snippet code. In this case, none image of **SSTA_7d** ImageCollection has 'system:time_start' property despite they have DOY and year properties. You need to fix this before considering why **HS_SSTA_7d** **ImageCollection** is empty.

```
.
.
.
var SSTA_7d =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
      return DOY.map(function(d) {
      d = ee.Number(d);
      var SSTA_date = series_daily.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(d, d.add(7), 'day_of_year'));
                      
      var img_last = ee.Image(SSTA_date.sort('system:time_start',true));
      var size = SSTA_date.size();

      var SSTA_filtered_7d = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(size.eq(0),
                                            ee.Image.constant(0).toFloat(),
                                            ee.Image(series_daily.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                                            .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(d, d.add(7), 'day_of_year'))
                                            .mean()
                                            )));
      
      return SSTA_filtered_7d.set('year', y)
              .set('DOY', d)
              .set('system:time_start', img_last.get('system:time_start'));

  });
  }).flatten()
);
.
.
.
//print(DHW_HS);
```

Comment: Thanks that's great i'll look into that, thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.